# Open detail on new activity when ListView item is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from MySQL database on Localhost server and displaying some  data *(username, email)* in `ListView` not complete. I want to open complete detail *(username, email, fathername, qualification, contact etc )* of clicked `ListView` item on a new activity.

Activity 1 code

```
lvViewAllData.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), SingleUser.class );
                    tvGetUsername = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow);
                    String username = tvGetUsername.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra("username", username );
                    startActivity( intent );
                }
            }
    );
```

Activity 2 code where i want to display complete data

```
public class SingleUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    String GET_USERNAME;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_user_layout);
        GET_USERNAME = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUsernameSigleUser);
        textView.setText(GET_USERNAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have call query to fetch data from MySQL database.

Comment: yes i'm getting every thing from database

Comment: I'm facing problem while displaying data to other activity. kindly help me

Comment: 1. Pass unique id from First Activity to second Activity. 2 Call Query to fetch data according to id passed. After getting data, show data to Second Activity

Comment: yes exactly i dont know how to pass it. in above code i am passing username so that i can fetch data according to this username. but it's not working

Comment: what is the problem with that code?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: ok Shane i share it

Comment: Where is this `tvUsernameDisplayRow` ? inside activity's xml or adapter item xml

Comment: the code is shared let me know if anyone got it

Comment: Tejas Pandya its an id of activity's xml

Answer (score 0):

```
lvViewAllData.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    CompleteData completeData = customAdopter.getItem(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), SingleUser.class );
                    String username = completeData.getUsername();
                    intent.putExtra("username", username );
                    startActivity( intent );
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: can u please help me if in initialize tvGetUsername  outside to click then how can i get username dynamically when item is clicked?

Comment: inside onItemClick, you can get data like this

yourArrayList.get(position).username

Comment: `You are initializing tvGetUsername on list item click` , no he is not .

Comment: @TejasPandya check this line tvGetUsername = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow); on onItemClick

Comment: 'TextView tvGetUsername' is not defined inside click listener . dont confuse 

`TextView tvGetUsername = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow);` with  `tvGetUsername = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow);`

Comment: @SalahuddinAyubi Can you please share your CustomAdopter code?

Comment: @kinjalshah i share it wait a minut

Comment: @kinjalshah i've shared please check it

Comment: Change                     `tvGetUsername = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow);`  to                     `tvGetUsername = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.tvUsernameDisplayRow);`